# ActivityでgetSupportFragmentManagerを呼び出すには

Tags: android, fragment, dialog

FragmentActivityを継承していない（Activityを継承）しているクラスで、getSupportFragmentManagerを呼び出したいと思っております。

過去のOSでもダイアログを表示する必要があるため、
getFragmentManagerは使えません。

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
```

代用にこちらを使用してます。

【試したこと】
・ActivityからfragmentActivityへのキャスト

```
this.fragmentActivity = (FragmentActivity) activity;
```

こちらは失敗し、このようなエラーがでました。

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException:○○.MainActivity
```

やはり、不可能なのでしょうか。ヒントを頂ければ嬉しいです。

Answer (score 1):

> FragmentActivityを継承していない（Activityを継承）しているクラスで

Activity を継承することを選択して、その上で Activity だったものを FragmentActivity にキャストするのではなく、元からクラスを FragmentActivity から継承したものを使います。そのクラスの中で、`getSupportFragmentManager()`をコールするだけです。

つまり、そのクラス自体を、`extends FragmentActivity` として書き換えれば、`getSupportFragmentManager()`をコールして、  android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager オブジェクトを得ることができるようになります。